# Logcat won't show up

Tags: android, logcat

I am somewhat new to android and I am setting up my view perspectives (that i am fairly anal about). I want to have logcat showing on my normal editing perspective.

But I go into Window>Show View>Other Views.. select android and logcat. And the window does not show up.  Sometimes it grayed out.

If I switch to the DDMS perspective it shows up just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

thanks!

[image]

Comment: I just checked, it appears for me in the "Other" view list opened from the standard java perspective. Are you absolutely sure that it's missing?

Comment: for when it's grayed out: is it possibly hidden somewhere but already showing? maybe detached and behind main eclipse windows, or in some minimized tab inside eclipse.

Comment: I kind of suspect it is showing. I use a laptop and move between different monitor configurations so it may just be off the screen someplace. But I can't get it to show up. Is there a way to force close it even though I can't see it?

Comment: I've checked and I am simply not seeing it. But it could very well be on a monitor screen that isn't there. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try the following in eclipse.

Windows->close all Perspective

Windows->Open perspective->Java EE

Window->show view->other->Android->LogCat

Comment: it's not listed in general on my computer. it's listed in android and it's grayed out.

Comment: what version of the Android SDK and Eclipse you are using?

Comment: eclipse 3.6.2 and android Version: 10.0.0.v201102162101-104271

Comment: Gosh, this really saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

to solve the problem reset the setting by following this print screen on right corner java->reset will reset the settings [image]

than run your app and console and logcat will apear

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if `adb logcat` is working as in some cases logging is disabled with kernel options by default (on the device).

Comment: This is already answered.  If it is grayed out, it is already open.  You will need to tile/cascade, etc in eclipse or desktop to find/close/locate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but it had to do with my page not updating. I had a shortcut bar with Logcat(Depreciated) and when I added Logcat View it would not update the shortcut bar. I had to move the bar and then it updated the icons.

TL;DR - Try moving shortcut bars around